# Where Condition in Lambda with two values

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

```
public enum Values
{
    [Description("All Fabs")]
    value1 = 0,
    [Description("Fab 1")]
    value2 = 1,
    [Description("Fab 2")]
    value3 = 2,
    [Description("Fab 3")]
    value4 = 3,
    [Description("Fab 4")]
    value5 = 4,
    [Description("Fab 5")]
    value6 = 5           
}

public static Dictionary<int, string> ConvertEnumToDictionary<T>()
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    if(!type.IsEnum)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
    Dictionary<int, string> result = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    bool header = true;
    foreach(var field in type.GetFields())
    {
        if(header)
        {
            header = false;
            continue;
        }
        var attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(field, typeof(DescriptionAttribute)) as DescriptionAttribute;
        if(attribute != null)
        {
            result.Add((int)field.GetValue(null), attribute.Description);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

`Displays.ConvertEnumToDictionary<Values>().Where(i => (i.Key == value2 || i.Key == value1));`

the above line produces diff results in development environment and in staging environment.

In development it returns both the values but in staging sometimes it returns one value only (either `value1` or `value2`) and sometimes both.

Please help me find out the problem here.

Comment: Have you checked in debug if `Type.GetFields()` always returns 2 fields? What happens when you step through the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be because of this sentence in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch9714z3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Your code must not depend on the order in which fields are returned, because that order varies.

You're skipping the first item you iterate (your `header` variable). That will only work if the fields come back in the same order every time.

Try removing the code that skips the "header", and instead getting the field value into a variable and checking whether `value.Equals(default(T))`. That would skip the enum value with 0 as its backing integer value.

Comment: Thanks joe. I will try it and let you know. and thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

It may be linked to the "header" part while iterating raw fields. Prefer this manner to iterate thru enum values:

```
FieldInfo[] fields = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
```

Then you can start at offset-0:

```
for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; i++)
```